# Programming best practice - loop objects

Tags: javascript, algorithm

This may seem like a broad question, but it struck me when I was optimizing code on one of my projects.

Let's say I have an **array of objects which I need to update.**

And let's say that each of the objects has a method for itself that **counts some application state** *(which stays the same until the very end of the loop of the objects)*.

```
for *every* object in *array*
object.update();

inside object:
... compute.something();
```

This results in a process where every objects "computes" this value for itself and applies it.

So there I was sitting and thought like, what If I get a list of all the items that basicly compute the **same thing** and compute it before the loop and push the result into the loop itself?

**Resulting in something like**

```
computeData

for *every* object in *array*
object.update(computeData);

inside object:
apply(computedData);
```

With this structure I don't really have to compute everything n-times where n is the size of the object array but just **once**.

I never heard of this approach before and wanted to ask if this is something that is being used/taught/applied or nah? I know I didn't find any gold or so, just wanted to know your opinion if I shall focus on this structure in the future right from the beginning... ?

Comment: There is a name for the strategy of computing something only once instead of repeatedly -- common sense :)

Comment: Well of course if you want to update all elements with same calculated value, then yes you should calculate it once outside the loop, but if the calculus depends on elements, well then nah

Comment: Could you provide a specific example of such a situation?

Comment: Haha John :D great comment - but trust me, once I made this slight change to my object arrays with a lot objects it was an eye opener :D spend next hours looking for gaps where this can be applied :D

Comment: This is called caching, it's concept lies at the core of computing science and has been around since computing science was conceived. To answer the question: yes, focus on this in the future. If you do not, your program is bad.

Comment: Yeah, I mean like I hope Im not entirely stupid, I hope, but in a lot lot lot of repos I saw the approach where this wasnt used .. And I know I heard dont "optimize" if it works - but I feel like since this I dont want to ever use anything else...

Comment: @OliverGoossens well the *dont optimize if it works* is only true if performance does not matter **at all**. In computing science, and most projects, performance **is** a huge factor. Therefor, during development these concepts are constantly used. I wouldn't call you stupid for noting the value of this, in fact it's a sign of you being a critical thinker. However it's pretty much the standard in the world of development and people will usually *correct* you if you *don't* apply this rather than *congratulate* you when you *do* apply it.

Comment: @Glubus gotcha :) thank you (this was a P5.js project with html5 canvas graphics running 60FPS, the performance isnt really a factor until it gets below 60 FPS)

Comment: @OliverGoossens Don't forget to close this question.

Comment: Programmers twiddling front-panel switches on a PDP were pulling calculations outside of loops before there were even programming languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear about your question, it but looks like possibly three design patterns:

1 - Memoization

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization

The result of a frequently called function is cached (for a given input) the first time it is called with that input. This means that calling repeatedly means that the same work is not re-done each time.

2 - Observer pattern

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

Objects can be registered to listen to changes / triggers in another object. In this case, each of your array of objects could register with the central 'loop' object, and send back values when the "I want the data to be updated" action is triggered.

3 - Callback pattern

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)

More generally, the idea of the separate objects being able to return values when requested by the central object.

If you are having these kinds of thoughts, I suggest you read up on [Design Patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern). The classic ["Gang of Four"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) book is quite old now, but the ideas still stand.

Comment: Thank you for this input :) Ill take my time and read into this

Comment: I wouldn't even go that far. What OP describes is simply pulling a calculation outside of a loop--an optimization that pre-dates programming languages.